# How to deal with cannot assign requested address: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:5000 (localhost) failed

Tags: apache, asp.net-core, httpd.conf

Looks like I'm facing the reverse proxy problem of my Apache 2.4 (CentOS 8)

```
[Mon Jun 14 10:41:52.911113 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 254199:tid 140268464502528] (99)Cannot assign requested address: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:5000 (localhost) failed

[Mon Jun 14 10:41:52.911154 2021] [proxy_http:error] [pid 254199:tid 140268464502528] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:52865] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
```

I'm stuck with this, anybody can help me?

My reverse proxy as follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName xx.example.com
    ServerAlias xx.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/requests.log combined

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RewriteEngine On

    ProxyPass /myapp/api/          http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse /myapp/api/  http://localhost:5000/

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xx.example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xx.example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

my program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseUrls("http://127.0.0.1:5000");
                });
```

Comment: show us you at least tried to verify localhost:5000 is even up and responding to http commands, something like the output of  "curl -v http://localhost:5000"

Comment: [root@localhost conf]# netstat -tanpl|grep 5000

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21888/dotnet
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40850         127.0.0.1:5000          TIME_WAIT   -

Comment: Perfect, the port is there, now use curl and show it works.